# WebResponses blocked when UI is busy

Tags: asynchronous, httpwebrequest, windows-phone-7.1, system.reactive

I have a little problem with Windows Phone 7 WebRequests.
In my program are few "web process" - each of those must send one or more REST-s message to server. Informations from response to this message are used in next REST, so all WebRequest must be send in the proper sequence. So, to easily synchronize all messages I created method like this:

```
//There was some try-catch blocks,  I cut them because they are not important 
//for the problem
public string SendString(string URL, string message)
        {
            WebRequest wr = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);
            wr.Method = "POST";
            var req = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<Stream>(wr.BeginGetRequestStream, wr.EndGetRequestStream);
            var resp = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(wr.BeginGetResponse, wr.EndGetResponse);
            WebResponse WR = req().SelectMany(reqStream =>
                {
                    byte[] stream = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                    reqStream.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);
                    reqStream.Close();
                    return resp();
                })
                .First();
            Stream respStream = WR.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(respStream, UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
            String response = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            _acctualResponse = response;

            return _acctualResponse;
        }
```

Of course, "web process" Is running asynchronous:

```
Observable.Start(() => _registration.Execute(String.Empty)).Subscribe();
```

Problem is, that when UI thread is busy, responses are not coming until UI thread is free. I don't have idea why. Maybe someone will help me.

**EDIT**

I make some pseudo-diagram to visualize structure of my appliaction.
Each process must be asynchronous, but also, each action must wait for result of previous one.

[image: Application flow]

**EDIT 2**

Code of `Action` part, in all cases is very simple and look like this one:

```
public override JsonMap.Response Perform(string token)
        {
            JsonMap.authenticationRequest dataToSend = new JsonMap.authenticationRequest
            {
                tid = token,
                platform = "wp7",
                version = "1.0.0",
                userid = ApplicationData.Instance.UserID
            };
            string jsonDataToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSend,Formatting.Indented,new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
            string jsonResponse = _webClient.SendString(_serviceURL, jsonDataToSend);
            Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonResponse);
            return response;

        }
```

Comment: You code is missing the `Action1`, `Action2`, `Action3` code. Makes it hard to give a full answer without them.

Comment: I coped some code of Action - only one, because each of them making very similar things - grabbling some data, serializing it, sending to SendString method and Deserializing result

Comment: I think the thing that you're doing wrong is moving in and out of the monad. Your `Perform` function should return an `IObservable<JsonMap.Response>` to stay in the monad and make things work smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is that you are calling `First()` which is a blocking call.

Whenever you call `First()` you are probably doing something wrong.

You've probably been lead down this "dark path" because your function signature is also a blocking signature. You need to change it to this:

```
public IObservable<string> SendString(string URL, string message)
```

Now you can write your function like this:

```
public IObservable<string> SendString(string URL, string message)
{
    WebRequest hwr = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);
    hwr.Method = "POST";

    Func<IObservable<Stream>> getRequest = 
        Observable
            .FromAsyncPattern<Stream>(
                hwr.BeginGetRequestStream,
                hwr.EndGetRequestStream);

    Func<Stream, IObservable<WebResponse>> getResponse = ...

    Func<WebResponse, string> getResult = ...

    return
        from rq in getRequest()
        from rp in getResponse(rq)
        select getResult(rp);
}
```

Note that there is a real neatness to the final query.

The `getResponse` function looks like this:

```
    Func<Stream, IObservable<WebResponse>> getResponse =
        st =>
        {
            var resp =
                Observable
                    .FromAsyncPattern<WebResponse>(
                        hwr.BeginGetResponse,
                        hwr.EndGetResponse);
            var bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
            st.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            st.Close();
            return resp();          
        };
```

And `getResult` looks like this:

```
    Func<WebResponse, string> getResult =
        wr =>
        {
            using (var st = wr.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(st, UTF8Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    return sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        };
```

Finally you need to subscribe to the resultant observable to get the result. You may need to call `ObserveOn` to get the call to come back to the UI thread.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Should `First`, even if it blocks matter since it's inside Start()? The default scheduler for `Start` is ThreadPool. It seems like something's still managing to run on his UI thread.

Comment: @Asti - The call to `First` doesn't seem to be called in the `Start` code. In any case, calling `First` is code smell. If you only need the first value it is better almost always to call `Take(1)` and still subscribe to the sequence so it doesn't block. It's best to stay inside the monad as long as absolutely possible.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Call to First is inside the Start code. I know that call First() is blocking, and that should be - as I say, this code is inside some process, that next call is depending on previous one, So i need to make some sequence of it. I edited my first post to visualize how its look.